# Why do some of my Rails path helpers have an _index suffix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a Rails route definition that looks something like this:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :feeds
  resources :push
end
```

`rake routes` generates the following output for it:

```
admin_feeds GET  /admin/feeds  {:controller=>"admin/feeds", :action=>"index"}
admin_push_index GET  /admin/push  {:controller=>"admin/push", :action=>"index"}
```

Why would would the path helper for `push` get the `_index` suffix, but not `feeds`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's all based on the plurality of the resource.  So if the resource name is plural, then it has no need to add an `_index` suffix since it's inferred.

If it is a singular resource name, then it adds the suffix for clarification since `admin_push` would typically be a `show` action instead of the `index` action.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use

```
resource :push
```

instead of

```
resources :push
```

to specify a singular resource. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing.html